# wiringPi compile issue on RPi 4B 64bit

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-4, c++, wiringpi

I am trying to compile my C++ project using CMake. My Raspberry Pi OS does include `/usr/include/wiringPi.h` and all the required `.so` files in `/usr/lib/`. Here is the output of `gpio -v` command:

```
gpio version: 2.52
Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Gordon Henderson
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type: gpio -warranty

Raspberry Pi Details:
  Type: Pi 4B, Revision: 02, Memory: 4096MB, Maker: Sony 
  * Device tree is enabled.
  *--> Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.2
  * This Raspberry Pi supports user-level GPIO access.
```

I did `#include <wiringPi.h>` in my project. However, I get errors when I try to build the project:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/.../**.so: undefined reference to `pinMode'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/.../**.so: undefined reference to `digitalWrite'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/.../**.so: undefined reference to `delay'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/.../**.so: undefined reference to `wiringPiSetup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I added `add_definitions(-std=c++0x -L/usr/lib/libwiringPi.so -lwiringPi)` to my CMakeList.txt, no success. Then, I tried compiling a simple `.c` code to see if this is a linking issue where again I get errors:

```
$ gcc -o test my_program.c -lwiringPi

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../lib/libwiringPi.so when searching for -lwiringPi
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/../lib/libwiringPi.so when searching for -lwiringPi
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libwiringPi.so when searching for -lwiringPi
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../libwiringPi.so when searching for -lwiringPi
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //lib/libwiringPi.so when searching for -lwiringPi
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libwiringPi.so when searching for -lwiringPi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lwiringPi
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there any issue with the [64bit](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=297260) CPU or what else can I do? My application requires turning On/Off relay switch on certain GPIOs. I don't think I2C is a workaround here. Also I would prefer not to download/install libraries written by random developers. My very last option would be invoking python functions through `RPi.GPIO` library (all just works fine in Python), though c++ workaround is what I am looking for.

Comment: wiringPi is a library written by a random developer.  You will need to find a copy of the source and build the library if you want to use it.  There are other C libraries written by random developers: pigpio and bcm2835 are the obvious ones.

Comment: I should also mention lgpio and the /dev/gpiochip library.

Comment: @joan thanks, you are right. `wiringPi` however, is OK as it comes with Raspbian OS, at least, I didn't need to install it. I will take a look on those two.

Comment: pigpio also comes with Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-deprecated/ it's completely unsupported on 64-bit systems.

Comment: @joan how long have you been a random developer?

Comment: @Milliways At a guess I'd say about the same time as you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried `BCM2835` out and it does the job, below is quick-start for those who  need it:

> BCM2835 is the MCU chip of the Raspberry Pi, whose library can often be used to access the GPIO on BCM 2835 chip. You can use the librarty to control the rigistors of a BCM2835 chip directly just like using STM32 library to control an STM32 chip. in contrast, the libraries of WiringPi or Python control GPIO by reading and writing device files on the Linux system.

To install BCM2835 and get to know PIN numbers, [follow this simple guide](https://www.techworked.com/install-bcm2835-library-in-raspberry-pi/) or try this out:

```
mkdir ~/BCM2835 && cd ~/BCM2835                  
wget http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/bcm2835-1.58.tar.gz                       
tar xvfz bcm2835-1.58.tar.gz;                      
cd bcm2835-1.58;                       
./configure;                      
make;        
sudo make install
```

To make sure you are all set, you can build a sample program `test.cpp` and include `bcm2835.h`:

```
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (!bcm2835_init()) return 1;
    std::cout << "BCM2835 is all set!" << std::endl
    return 0;
}
```

and build it using `g++`:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -lbcm2835
./test
```

NOTE: There might be other options as well other than BCM2835, like those were suggested in the comments. Thanks to those who contributed.